# javascript post xml controller read xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, post, controller

I would like to send an XML string as POST from javascript to server. The XML has this structure:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <Devices>
     <Device>
        <Id>212121</Id>
      <Accuracy>3</Accuracy>
     <BatteryVolts>12.34</BatteryVolts>
   </Device>
  <Device>
   <Id>212122</Id>
    <Accuracy>5</Accuracy>
    <BatteryVolts>12.14</BatteryVolts>
 </Device>
</Devices>
```

In javascript I use:

```
    var dd = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>< ... all xml goes here '
    $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            data: dd,
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            dataType: "xml",
            url: 'api/deviceapi',
            success: function (data) { var ok= 1;      },
            error: function (xhr) {    var ok = 0;    }
        });
```

In the controller:

```
public int Post(object message)
    {//parse message ...
        return 1;
    }
```

Once I get the xml into the controller I can parse it, no problem. Please help, thank you!

Comment: looks like your server is expecting the xml as the request body so try to set `contentType: "application/xml"`

Answer (score 0):

```
var defineClass = function () {
    var inheritance = function inheritance() { };
    return function defineClass(data) {
        var classname = data.name,
            superclass = data.extend || Object,
            constructor = data.construct || function () { },
            methods = data.methods || {},
            statics = data.statics || {},
            borrows,
            provides;
        if (!data.borrows) {
            borrows = [];
        }
        else {
            if (data.borrows instanceof Array) {
                borrows = data.borrows;
            }
            else {
                borrows = [data.borrows];
            };
        };
        if (!data.provides) {
            provides = [];
        }
        else {
            if (data.provides instanceof Array) {
                provides = data.provides;
            }
            else {
                provides = [data.provides];
            };
        };
        inheritance.prototype = superclass.prototype;
        var proto = new inheritance();
        for (var i = 0; i < borrows.length; i++) {
            var c = borrows[i];
            for (var p in c.prototype) {
                if (typeof c.prototype[p] != "function") continue;
                proto[p] = c.prototype[p];
            }
        }
        for (var p in methods) {
            proto[p] = methods[p];
        };
        proto.constructor = constructor;
        constructor.superclass = superclass.prototype;
        if (classname) {
            proto.classname = classname;
        };
        for (var i = 0; i < provides.length; i++) {
            var c = provides[i];
            for (var p in c.prototype) {
                if (typeof c.prototype[p] != "function") {
                    continue;
                };
                if (p == "constructor" || p == "superclass") {
                    continue;
                };
                if (p in proto && typeof proto[p] == "function" && proto[p].length == c.prototype[p].length) {
                    continue;
                };
                throw new Error("Class " + classname + " are not provided method " + c.classname + "." + p);
            };
        };
        constructor.prototype = proto;
        for (var p in statics) {
            constructor[p] = statics[p];
        };
        return constructor;
    }
}();
var EndPoint = (function () {
    return defineClass({
        name: "EndPoint",
        construct: function (urlObj) {
            var myUrl,
                myScheme,
                myDefaultScheme = "http",
                myLogin,
                myPassword,
                myHost,
                myDefaultHost = "localhost",
                myIP,
                myDefaultIP = "127.0.0.1",
                myPort,
                myDefaultPort = "80",
                myPath,
                myDefaultPath = "/",
                myOptions,
                myAnchor;
            var self = this;
            var parse_url = /^(?:([A-Za-z]+):)?(\/{0,3})(?:([A-Za-z]+):([A-Za-z]+)@)?([0-9.\-A-Za-z]+)(?::(\d+))?(?:\/([^?#]*))?(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?$/;
            var result = parse_url.exec(urlObj);
            var names = ['url', 'scheme', 'slash', 'login', 'password', 'host', 'port', 'path', 'query', 'hash'];
            var i;
            for (i = 0; i < names.length; i += 1) {
                switch (names[i]) {
                    case 'url':
                        myUrl = result[i];
                        break;
                    case 'scheme':
                        myScheme = result[i];
                        break;
                    case 'slash':
                        break;
                    case 'login':
                        myLogin = result[i];
                        break;
                    case 'password':
                        myPassword = result[i];
                        break;
                    case 'host':
                        myHost = result[i];
                        break;
                    case 'port':
                        myPort = result[i];
                        break;
                    case 'path':
                        myPath = result[i];
                        break;
                    case 'query':
                        myOptions = result[i];
                        break;
                    case 'hash':
                        myAnchor = result[i];
                        break;
                }
            }
            this.scheme = myScheme;
            this.login = myLogin;
            this.password = myPassword;
            this.host = myHost;
            this.ip = myIP;
            this.port = myPort;
            this.path = myPath;
            this.options = myOptions;
            this.anchor = myAnchor;
            this.url = myUrl;
        },
        methods: {
            ValidateIP: function (ip) {
                return /^(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$/.test(ip);
            },
            ValidateUrl: function (url) {
                return /^(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/.test(url);
            },
            ValidateShortUrl: function (url) {
                if (/^\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/.test(url)) {
                    return true;
                };
                if (/^[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/.test(url)) {
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    })
}());
var QueryType = function QueryType() {
    if (!(this instanceof QueryType)) {
        return new QueryType(arguments[0]);
    };
    this.endPoint = arguments[0]["endPoint"];
    this.envelope = arguments[0]["envelope"];
    this.type = arguments[0]["type"];
    this.headers = arguments[0]["headers"];
    this.callback_success = arguments[0]["callback_success"];
    this.callback_failure = arguments[0]["callback_failure"];
    this.timeout = arguments[0]["timeout"];
    this.username = arguments[0]["username"];
    this.password = arguments[0]["password"];
};
var TaskManager = function () {
    if (!(this instanceof TaskManager)) {
        return new TaskManager();
    };
    var instance;
    TaskManager = function () {
        return instance;
    };
    TaskManager.prototype = this;
    instance = new TaskManager();
    instance.constructor = TaskManager;
    function Request() {
        if (!(this instanceof Request)) {
            return new Request();
        };
        var instance;
        Request = function () {
            return instance;
        };
        Request.prototype = this;
        instance = new Request();
        instance.constructor = Request;
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
        instance.send = function (query, callback, errorHandler) {
            try { netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalBrowserRead"); } catch (e) { };
            httpRequest.abort();
            if ((query.username == undefined) || (query.password == undefined)) {
                httpRequest.open(query.type, query.endPoint.url, true);
            }
            else {
                httpRequest.open(query.type, query.endPoint.url, true, query.username, query.password);
            };
            if (query.headers != null) {
                for (var i = 0; i < query.headers.length; ++i) {
                    httpRequest.setRequestHeader(query.headers[i][0], query.headers[i][1]);
                }
            }
            else {
                httpRequest.setRequestHeader("SOAPAction", '""');
                httpRequest.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
            };
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
                    if (httpRequest.status == 200) {
                        callback(httpRequest.responseText);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (errorHandler) {
                            errorHandler(httpRequest.status, httpRequest.statusText);
                        }
                        else {
                            callback(null);
                        };
                    };
                };
            };
            switch (query.type) {
                case "POST":
                    httpRequest.send(query.envelope);
                    break;
                case "GET":
                    httpRequest.send(null);
                    break;
            }
        };
        instance.cancel = function () {
            httpRequest.abort();
        };
        return instance;
    };
    var httpHandler = Request();
    var queryQueue = [];
    var timeoutID = -1;
    var startedFlag = false;
    var currentQuery = null;
    var start = function () {
        if (queryQueue.length > 0) {
            startedFlag = true;
            currentQuery = queryQueue.shift();
            httpHandler.send(currentQuery,
                function (resp) {
                    if (timeoutID >= 0) {
                        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
                        timeoutID = -1;
                    };
                    currentQuery.callback_success(resp);
                    start();
                },
                function (resp) {
                    if (timeoutID >= 0) {
                        clearTimeout(timeoutID);
                        timeoutID = -1;
                    };
                    currentQuery.callback_failure(resp);
                    start();
                }
            );
        }
        else {
            startedFlag = false;
        };
    };
    instance.add = function (req) {
        if (req instanceof QueryType) {
            queryQueue.push(req);
            if (!startedFlag) {
                start();
            };
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        };
    };
    instance.stopCurrent = function () {
        httpHandler.cancel();
        timeoutID = -1;
        if ((currentQuery.callback_failure != undefined) && (currentQuery.callback_failure != null)) {
            currentQuery.callback_failure("<comm_error>COMM TIMEOUT</comm_error>");
        };
        start();
    };
    return instance;
};

//to send a request it must be
TaskManager().add(
    new QueryType({
        "endPoint": new EndPoint("http://***.***.***.***/api/deviceapi"),
        "type": "POST",
        "envelope": '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>< ... all xml goes here ',
        "callback_success": function (wResponse) { /* here we get a response from the server */ },
        "callback_failure": function (status, statusText) { },
        "timeout": 60
    })
);
```

Comment: If you please can provide a "how to use" for this bit of code :) Also this is for javascript. it returns  'defineClass' is undefined.

Comment: ISBN 0-596-10199-6 David Flanagan (Chapter 9 - Example: A defineClass( ) Utility Method)

Comment: You can also find the function here https://sourceforge.net/projects/singletonxhr/

Comment: My apologize for the huge piece of code. Meanwhile it is pure javaScript. And at the very end of the code you can see a sample of working code where you need to substitute the address of the server and the content of the message, as well as to substitute the function to handle the response from the server. If you want, I can rewrite the Task Manager in order that he would become more compatible with older browsers such as IE4.